# Proxmox Web Gui buttons greyed out

Tags: proxmox

[image]

I'm currently configuring a proxmox instance. I can make VMs and containers via the CLI, but I cannot in the web GUI. I have had a look at the docs and hunted around a bit, but so far I can't really see where to begin debugging this. If anyone has any pointers on what the issue *could* be , that would be extrememly helpful